# Flash animation dynamic speed

Tags: performance, flash, animation, dynamic

i'm wondering is there a possibility in flash to change animation speed dynamicly? For example if i move some slider it increase, or decrease animation speed. I know it could be done if animation would be made in actionscript, but if animation is complex and made in timeline what's then?

Comment: This question is massive. In short - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex animation in flash there can be only one choice, that is to use the [Greensock TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) library.

You can create complex animations using timeline max, which allows you to sequence tweens, delay tweens etc.

Anything you can dream up can be done using this library.